# Jquery Menu simultaneously animated

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to animate 2-3 divs simultaneously using jQuery?

My idea is when someone hovers on the menu, a horizontal bar will arise when animate and increases the width, along with the menu with `ul` `li` also.

My main problem is how to use the first logo `div`, then a horizontal bar div, and menu div simultaneously in jQuery.

```
<header4>
        <div class="row">
                <div id="logo2">
                <a href="index.html"><h1>Testing</h1></a>
                </div>
             <nav>
                <ul id="primary-nav" class="sf-menu">
                <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services & Products</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SStack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Stack Overflow</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- END .sf-menu navigation -->
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </nav>
            <!-- END nav -->
        </div>
        <!-- END .row -->
        </header4> 

<script>
$("#logo2").hover(function(){
  $("div.header4").animate({
    width: "900px"
  }, 1500 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: What the heck is `<header4>`? Perhaps learn HTML, first, then worry about JS/jQuery.

Comment: its HTML5 class,Perhaps you learn HTML5 first

Comment: There is no `header4` element in HTML5. There's `header`, and there's `h4`.

Comment: Umm... No. It's not. `<header>` is an HTML5 element and `<h4>` is an HTML element, but `<header4>` is a figment of your imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use CSS?  No jQuery is necessary.

See the following:  http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/menus/demo.html